# Android In-app Billing crash when retrieving item price

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement Android In-app Billing.

What I have done so far:

1. Added the `aidl` file.
2. Added the `util-helper` files.
3. Created the app on Play Console
4. Uploaded a `signed APK` and added a product to the Play Console.
5. Added some code in the `Shop.java` file. Which is working fine until I try to retrieve the item price (See code between: `//THIS IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES` under).

Here is the code that I am using inside `onCreate()` in `Shop.java`

```
onCreate() {

    //In App Billing
    key = "XXX";
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, key);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
                return;
            }

            if (mHelper == null) return;


            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            try {
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {

            }

        }
    });
}
```

And then the `mGotInventoryListener`:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // handle error
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
        boolean mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null);
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));



        //THIS IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES
        String price = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU).getPrice();
        //THIS IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES


        updateUI();
    }
};
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: example.com.app, PID: 4270
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String example.com.app.util.SkuDetails.getPrice()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at example.com.app.Shop$2.onQueryInventoryFinished(Shop.java:234)
                                                                               at example.com.app.util.IabHelper$2$1.run(IabHelper.java:711)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU);
```

returns SkuDetails object. But this object can be null

```
SkuDetails details = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU);
if (details == null) {
   return;
};
String price = details.getPrice();
```

Comment: But why is the details object empty?

Comment: 1. The premium item was not bought.
2. ITEM_SKU is not added in google.

Comment: what is returned by inventory.getAllPurchases() method ?

Comment: Think I found the reason: "You need to publish your application to Beta/Alpha to access inapp billing functionality."

Comment: But thank you for helping! I will implement your code to avoid this crash.